# ASP.net 4, MVC and scriptmanager syntax to use asp: ajax control toolkit elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**Context:**
I am new to MVC asp.net Framework 4. In my application i wish to update a partial view upon a user click event (using an ActionResult). In index.aspx i use the standard Ajax.BeginForm containg a div in which i render the partial view (which calls the ActionResult):

```
 *<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" })) 
      {  %>
    Name 
    <input id="txtName1" name="RoleName" type="text" value="" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="divToUpdate">
    <%--render what you want to update here.. --%>
    <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/SecurityMainPartialView.ascx", Model); %>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
    <% }%>*
```

The updating of the partial view works. However:

**The issue:**

In the Site.Master i had the form tag, which i had to remove becuase the partial view would redirect the action link to Index instead of search. in removing this i can no longer use the asp:scriptmanager tag which is needed to use the asp.tab etc etc...

I get the following error: *Control 'ctl00_MainContent_ScriptManager1' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.* error even on the ActionLinks in the site master.

Site master code:

```
*<body>
 <%--   <form id="form1" runat="server">
 --%>   <div id="container">
        <div id="header">    
            <h1 style="width: 1207px; margin-left: 0px">PROM (Promise Remote Order Management)</h1>

        <div id="menubar">
            **<li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
            <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Security", "SecurityMain", "Security")%></li>
            <li style="width: 1208px; height: 0px"><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>**
           </div>  
        </div> 
        <div id="content" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" >
                <p style="height: 132px; margin-top: 0px">
                </p>


          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>© footer stuff goes here!</p>
        </div>   
       </div>
<%--    </form>--%>
</body>
</html>*
```

**QUESTION:**

How can i incorporate the use of scripts (ScriptManager) in my Asp.net MVC 4 app? Do i use  MVC ScriptManager  or something else? I know we are not supposed to use script manager in MVC as it breaks the rules...what is my alternative.

Thank you any help would be greatly appricitaed.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use web controls in asp.net mvc application. You can do it but I don't recommend. You can use some javascript libs like jQuery, Ext.Js etc... to do async operations in your View.

I like jQuery it's easy, fast to learn and develop and cross-browser (works in i.e., firefox, chrome, etc...) and I've been using it on my web apps with asp.net mvc and works very fine. Take a look at this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ it will show to you some operations with ajax (get/post calls, json result etc...) usign jquery lib.

jQuery comes in default template of asp.net mvc of visual studio, use it :)

Cheers!

Comment: Hi I need to display information in a jstree that reside in tabs how can i do this without asp.tabContainers in a MVC app? Also how can i use ActionLink functionality. Could you give me some examples please?

Comment: Hi friend, you could use jQuery UI (ui.jquery.com) to do something like this, there are some components like tabs, modal window, autocomplete, buttons etc... in this libs that works with jquery.